# Writing simple C# logging framwork. Issue with TPL (Task.Factory.StartNew())

Tags: c#, logging, task-parallel-library

I am writing simple log framework where user can either log line by line or in batch. User Write(message) in his code and the based on bool flushEveryLine (true for each line, false for batch write), logs are written via by calling flush() method. 
The messages are created on main thread and when written to file, outputConsole or DebugConsole is on different thread using Task. List is what I want to synchronized between main thread and worker thread using TPL. So when TimerEvent happen, lost of messages should be written to the output. THe problem is messages changes Please see the message below.

```
    protected virtual void Write(LogMessage message)
    {
        if (!this.IsEnabled) // log enabled or disabled.
            return;
        List<Task> list = new List<Task>();
        foreach (Task task in _taskList)
        {
            if (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                list.Add(task);
        }
        _taskList = list;
        Task.WaitAll(_taskList.ToArray());
       lock(storage)
        {
            //Add message to messages
           **this.messages.Add(message);**

            if (FlushEveryLine)
                **Flush();**
        } 

    public void Flush()
    {

        if (messages.Count == 0)
            return;
        _taskToMessagesMap.Add(counter, this.messages);
       **Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FlushData(counter));**
        ++counter;
        if (counter > 30000) // reset counter after large increment.
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
        this.messages.Clear();// clear the messages to record new set of messages before writing.
    }

    protected virtual void FlushData(int index)
    {
        **List<LogMessage> messages = _taskToMessagesMap[index];**
        if (!IsEnabled) // logs enabled or not.
        {
            return;
        }
        lock (messages)
        {
            if (messages.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            IEnumerable<LogMessage> temp = messages.OrderBy(msg => msg.TimeStamp).ToArray();
             this.flush(temp);

        }
        return;

    }
```

Code explanation::
 _taskToMessagesMap = new Dictionary ();
// Dictionary to store counter and list of messages. This is hack as I want to test the behavior of List.

**Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FlushData(counter));**
//Actually I want to use Flush(messages) for each thread such that when FlushData() is called the messages that are passed should be used. But what I see when worker thread is executed it uses the current message list. I know list is pass by reference hence seeing this behaviour, but I am seeing this behavior with integer too in teh above example. 
Example: my dictionary has only one key {0} and all the test messages but when it enter worker thread it look for key 1. Why? Integer parameter should be pass by value. I am passing 0 as parameter when I create the worker thread. How can I fix this.

Please help as I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Closures close over variables not values. The new value is picked up in `FlushData` because the instruction that increments the `counter` variable being executed before the lambda passed to `StartNew` is executed.

A simple way around this is to take a snapshot of the current value in local variable.

```
int currentCounter = counter;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FlushData(currentCounter));
++counter;
```

**Update**

You need to make copies of the data for the tasks to work on so that other threads do not interfere with writing the messages. I would rewrite Flush and FlushData to look more like this:

```
public void Flush()
{
    if (messages.Count == 0)
        return;

    // make a copy of the list.
    var currentMessages = messages.ToList();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FlushData(currentMessages));
    messages.Clear();// clear the messages to record new set of messages before writing.
}

protected virtual void FlushData(IEnumerable<LogMessage> toBeFlushed)
{
    if (!IsEnabled) // logs enabled or not.
    {
        return;
    }

    IEnumerable<LogMessage> temp = toBeFlushed.OrderBy(msg => msg.TimeStamp).ToArray();
    this.flush(temp);
}
```

`Flush` should probably also take the lock on `storage` since it is a public method that could be called from anywhere. Currently, there is the possibility of messages getting lost.